# Facebook Graph API link with big thumbnail

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I need your help. Facebook released a list of new features in the last weeks. One of them are bigger thumbnails to the link posts. Example: http://postimg.org/image/l3pqh1h6p/

I’m using the Graph API and Facebook SDK for C#:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["message"] = post.Text;
parameters["link"] = post.LinkUrl;
parameters["name"] = post.LinkTitle;
parameters["picture"] = post.Image.InternalFileName;

FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
facebookClient.AppId = AuthConfig.FacebookAppId;
facebookClient.AppSecret = AuthConfig.FacebookAppSecret;
var publishedResponse = facebookClient.Post(pageAccessToken, "/" + facebookDestinationPageId + "/feed", parameters);
```

Unfortunately I see the bigger thumbnail only on my page I posted (facebookDestinationPageId) but on my start page (facebook.com/?sk=nf) I can see only the small one.
Here an example: http://postimg.org/image/lnfd59k4b/

When I post the same content manually (via Facebook itself), on both places I can see the bigger thumbnail.

Is there a problem in my code / missing paramether / or Graph API does not support my case?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

i found the solution: there is no problem in my code, the Facebook App should be added in the white list.

The source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1434807550079885

"...Currently to get access to this you'll need to contact your account manager or the PMD team - if you're working with neither we don't currently have a way to request access, but will possibly make this publicly available in the future..."

Comment: Some IP's are blacklisted by facebook , You need to change the IP  and try. It happened me long time back